# django-rest-framework PUT rewriting read-only slug field

Tags: put, django-rest-framework

First of all, I am overriding my view's `get_object()` method in order to URL-decode the slug value (URL-encoding is needed because the value contains slashes):

```
class MyDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        ...
        slug = unquote(self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None))
```

So while the slug value in the URL is URL-encoded, the data in the model is not.  (Maybe there's a better way to do this; please let me know.)

Anyway, this seems to work in that a GET finds the correct record.  When I try to do a PUT however, the field gets updated with the URL-encoded version, even though it is included in the serializer's meta-class' `read_only_fields` member.

The issue seems to be in `UpdateModelMixin`'s `pre_save()` method in mixins.py line 152:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    ...
    if pk:
        setattr(obj, 'pk', pk)

    if slug:
        setattr(obj, slug_field, slug)
```

It would appear that these are here to support creating a new resource via PUT, as mentioned in https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/328.  Is it not handling my case properly?  Or is there something I should be doing to circumvent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pk and/or slug are set in the `pre_save` method because they're implicit in the URL.  (As opposed to the request data, which is handled by the serializer.)

If you really need to change the behavior you can do so by overriding the `pre_save` method, although it's not obvious to me why you need it to do something different.

`the field gets updated with the URL-encoded version`

Surely that's correct - if the object does exist and it's been looked up by the slug from the URL, then setting the slug field from the URL won't actually change it.  If the object doesn't exist, then the slug needs to be set.

Comment: The slug value is URL-encoded, whereas the model data is not; the PUT updates the model data to the URL-encoded version.  Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Gotcha.  Then yup, you'll need to override `pre_save` accordingly.  Something like `obj.slug = unquote(self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None))`